# Wrapping bit.dev components with a ThemeProvider

Tags: material-ui, bit.dev, themeprovider

I want to start using bit.dev to manage React components across multiple apps. Each app is wrapped with a Theme provider.

The bit.dev playground is failing to render the components since they are trying to consume a theme but they are not wrapped in a theme provider.

Is there a way to wrap all components in a provider but only when being used within the playground UI?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

register a Provider in your env, like so:
https://harmony-docs.bit.dev/aspects/envs/#preview

Be careful, as this will also wrap your documentation.

Comment: The link above no longer seems to work. The updated docs seem to be found here: https://bit.dev/docs/react-env/component-previews#composition-providers